# How to get to a running "hello world" with OpenCL on Windows?

Tags: windows, opencl, intel

I want to try and use OpenCL on Windows, with a CPU, something I've not done before (I've used OpenCL on Linux on NVIDIA cards).

So,

- I visited Intel's website, downloaded `http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/vcp/13794/opencl_runtime_18.1_x64_setup.msi`, and installed it.
- I have Cygwin installed with g++ 7.4.0 and clang++ 8.0.1

What steps do I need to take in order to compile and run a program invoking some kind of "hello world" kernel, say:

```
__kernel void vectorAdd(
        __global float* result,
        __global const float* lhs,
        __global const float* rhs,
        int length)
{
    int pos = get_global_id(0);
    if (pos < length) {
        result[pos] = lhs[pos] + rhs[pos];
    }
}
```

My question: What steps do I need to take to realize that?

<sub>PS - If you suggest I download a non-Cygwin MS compiler, I'm willing to - as long as it's not a commercial for-pay product.</sub>

Comment: What problem did you run into?

Comment: @IInspectable:  Don't know what to do next. It doesn't look like a header and a library I could include and link against have been installed; or perhaps I didn't look in the right place? Also, would like to know if I could just use Cygwin-based compilers or whether I need something else.

Comment: why are you using Cygwin anyway? What does it have to do with OpenCL?

Comment: @Hashman: It doesn't, I just happen to be a Cygwin kind of a guy... but like I said, if that's a problem I can get another compiler.

Comment: Windows or not - you'll find a simple OpenCL program here: https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/